Device on lan to obtain public ip address
I don't know if this is possible at all. I have a mikrotik router connected to a modem acting as bridge. I have several devices connected to the router (dhcp) via ethernet and wifi, all working fine. However, I have a cable tv box which when connected to the wireless/ethernet network it obtains a valid local ip address but does not show channels. When this box is connected directly to the modem via ethernet (hence obtaining a public ip) it works. So my question is: Is it possible to connect this tv box to my lan but configure Mikrotik to assign this box a public ip? My WAN is dynamic. thanks

The problem is not that your tv box is not getting a public ip, but it is that there is a protection in place where it needs to be authorized by the modem itself.
The only way this will work, is if the tv box is connected to the modem directly.
You can disable bridge mode on the modem, so all LAN ports work, then set a DMZ rule for the connection to the mikrotik so your portforwarding still works, and connect any tv's to the other LAN ports.

Remove one of your Mikrotik router's Ethernet ports from the existing LAN bridge, then create a new bridge that contains the existing WAN port plus the separate TV port.
Make sure to add the new bridge to the 'WAN' interface list (for the correct firewall and NAT rules to apply). Finally, move your WAN DHCP client from ether1 to the new bridge.
(Note: Most Mikrotik routers only support hardware acceleration for one bridge at a time, so you should uncheck "Hardware offload" on the TV port's settings. It'll then go through the router's CPU, but that's the same as what happens to routed packets from the LAN, so it's not a big deal.)
With many ISPs, the problem is not "public address" but that there are multiple VLANs available on the WAN port – i.e. entirely separate networks distinguished by 802.1Q VLAN tags. (Typically the "IPTV" VLAN actually uses private addresses.)
